# UN/Edifact Segment Terminator

Tags: edi, x12, edifact

I understand that edifact syntax for the segment terminator is character " ' ". I have a situation where I receive an edifact file with no segment terminators

example instead of IFT+3+XYZCOMPANY AVAILABILITY' my segments ends like IFT+3+XYZCOMPANY AVAILABILITY without the terminator.

I would highly appreciate anyone who could explain to me the theory behind this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A segment terminator is always required. If there truly is no segment terminator, the EDI document is not valid by the EDIFACT standard.

It may be that they are actually using a CR/LF as the segment terminator. Although not good practice or valid EDIFACT, if you can set your software to accept a CR/LF as a segment terminator it should solve your issue.

To add to this, a segment terminator can be defined in the UNA segment eg. UNA:+.? ' where the 6th character will be the segment terminator. This is not required for a valid EDIFACT document.

Comment: It is also not unusual in circumstances like this to look at the document via a Hex Editor.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andrew, I am using Smooks framework to process edifact data. In this scenario smooks doesn't validate the edifact format with the segment terminator.

Comment: Thank Tom, Actually you are correct when I add the  UNA:+.? ' segment at the top Smooks validate the edifact correctly.

Comment: You should be able to override the delimiters with `<medi:delimiters escape="?" component=":" sub-component="^" field="+" segment="\r" />`